# Bring Timeline animation to top

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movie that adds a MovieClip to it's stage in the constructor, i Also have an animation on the timeline that plays on certain events. Everything is working, except the movie I need the movie on the timeline to be the top layer, it is on the bottom currently.

```
public Class BallCollision extends MovieClip{
    public function BallCollision(){
       mcBall = new MovieClip();
       stage.addChild(mcBall);
        //Adds stuff to the movie clip
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

1. Create a container on the timeline called 'container' and then add `mcBall` to that instead. This container will be on a layer underneath the existing animation.
2. Place all of the existing animation into a MovieClip and give it an instance name like `animation`. Whenever you add something to the stage, also use `stage.addChild(animation)` to bring it back to the top.

Obviously option 1 is preferable, but I've offered option 2 for the sake of free knowledge.

Comment: Option 2 is a really nasty trick! You could rather use [`setChildIndex()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_fr/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex%28%29)

Comment: Thanks. How do you create a container in the timeline? I'm new to this.

Comment: @Colin Simply create a new layer and draw a box, select that box and right click it and then select convert to symbol. When the dialogue appears, select MovieClip and hit OK. Then select the box again and open properties. In the instance name field write `container` (or whatever you want). Then place that box at 0,0. Finally, double click the box and then delete the graphic so that it is an empty MovieClip.